# Django migration error involving m2m field

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, database-migration

I am trying to modify my creator field from a ForeignKey to a ManyToManyField in hope of being able to select many users to be the creator.

When I make the change in my code, I receive the following error when making the migration:
"You cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields."

Would anyone know how to make this change possible for the migration to be successful?

Please see my code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Name of client"), max_length=100)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_("client"),
                            related_name='creator')
    start = models.DateTimeField(_("start"))
    end = models.DateTimeField(_("end"), help_text=_("The end time must be later than the start time."))
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("calendar"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove your ForeignKey, create and run migrations, and then add your ManyToManyField. Django currently can't do this in a single step.